# How to set variables with multi values in GitLab CI/CD?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am trying to edit yaml file to construct ci/cd in a gitlab project, troubled with the variables problem. I set a variable whose value is file path, and the number of file paths is multiple, so that I can use the words `rules: changes: '$var'`. But how can I set the variables with multi values? If I use the wildcards, just like this: `variables: COMMON_FILE: ./{ci/*,camke/*,*.yml}`, Then use `rules: changes: '$COMMON_FILE'` in the job, it will cause such error:"Local file'./ci/*' does not exist". If I reduce the number of file path, like this: `COMMON_FILE: ./ci/*`, it will not work yet. If the variable is like this: `variables: COMMON_FILE: ci/*`, it's ok. It seems that a file path with the prefix './' will not work. If I don't use wildcards, I must set more variables. Thus, is there any way that a variable could have multi values in the yaml file of gitlab ci/cd?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a CI/CD variable that is an array of values, but you can use shell scripting techniques for similar behavior.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#store-multiple-values-in-one-variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).